# Adding Minutes to Timestamp Hive

Tags: hive, timestamp

I am trying to add/subtract 14 minutes to a time interval I have but keep receiving errors or null

I am doing

```
select f.act_arrv_dtmz, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('f.ACT_ARRV_DTMZ')+840)
```

but I keep receiving an error. I am also trying it using CAST

```
select act_dprt_dtmz, CAST(act_dprt_dtmz as timestamp) - cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(act_dprt_dtmz)+840) as timestamp) from heart_beat_data_temp;
```

**this doesnt give the right time and when i put the variable in quotes**

```
select act_dprt_dtmz, CAST(act_dprt_dtmz as timestamp) - cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('act_dprt_dtmz')+840) as timestamp) from heart_beat_data_temp;
```

**it gives me null**

I would expect whatever the act_dprt_dtmz timestamp is plus 14 minutes

Comment: select act_dprt_dtmz, CAST(act_dprt_dtmz as timestamp) - cast(from_unixtime(840) as timestamp) from heart_beat_data_temp; //this seems to work better but the time wont convert back

Answer (score 4):

Hope this works :-)

```
select current_timestamp() as current_time,
        from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(current_timestamp())+840) as added_time;


+-------------------------+----------------------+--+
|      current_time       |      added_time      |
+-------------------------+----------------------+--+
| 2019-03-27 16:48:38.38  | 2019-03-27 17:02:38  |
+-------------------------+----------------------+--+
```

Answer (score 1):

E.g. Your current time in your specific timezone + 10 minutes:

```
select date_format(
        from_utc_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'Europe/Madrid') + INTERVAL 10 minutes,
        'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
     as PLUS_10_MIN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "interval" type with different qualifiers (seconds, minutes, hours, days, months, years):

```
select f.act_arrv_dtmz, f.act_arrv_dtmz + interval 14 minutes;
select f.act_arrv_dtmz, f.act_arrv_dtmz - interval 14 minutes;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.